# C# Application does not show the icon in the executable

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I am facing this strange issue. I built a C# application in Windows 7. It was showing the proper icon for the exe file, that I had set. I tested in other windows 7 systems, no issues so far.

When I moved the exe file to an Windows XP system, it was not showing the icon, but rather the  default icon ( icon similar to a floppy disk).

Any idea  what could be the reason ?

Thanks

Comment: The default icon is not similar to a floppy disk; maybe you have a corrupt install of XP.

Comment: Is it possible that the icon you're using is too big (in terms of its dimensions) for XP?  Or will an icon file that's too big get scaled down automatically?  Look up the icon sizes that Win7 can use vs the sizes that WinXP uses.

Comment: Size, I am not sure. I was using 128x128 in Windows 7 which worked fine. I will reduce the size and check it again. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post and upload the icon so we can see if there is anything weird about it.

Comment: I am so sorry, I have been trying to upload the icon, I donot know, the stackoverflow page is not rendered properly in my system. The entire strip ( consisting of upload button) is missing.

Comment: Looks like, WinXP does not support 128x128 icon size. I scaled down the icon size to 32x32 and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on XP, the max icon size is help in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

On my system, `Shell Icon Size` is set to *33*

You may change it to larger values, but there will be a slightly longer delay as windows loads in the appropriate size icon
There is apparently no limit, but having icons of 1024x1024 would be a little excessive (not to mention the loading time required)